# Displaying content from javascript using AppendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, each

I'm using the Trello API along with javascript/jquery to create a summarized view of a Trello board. I'm fairly new to jquery and I'm having trouble using appendTo to correctly lay out my page.

Below is the HTML I'm getting once the javascript content is returned. My goal is for the `<h3>` and `<p>` tags to be in their own div (so each "List Title" is contained in a separate div), but instead I can only seem to get the `<p>` tags in the div, with the `<h3>` just outside of it.

```
<div id="output">
    <div id="boards">
        <h3 class="board">List Title 1</h3>
        <div>
            <p class="card">Card 1 Name</p>
            <p class="card">Card 2 Name</p>
            ...
        </div>
        <h3 class="board">List Title 2</h3>
        <div>
            <p class="card">Card 1 Name</p>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript. The base HTML I'm starting with just contains `<div id="output></div>`; all other HTML is being added through this javascript. I believe the issue has to do with how I have nested .each() methods and how I'm using appendTo() within them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var $boards = $("<div>")
        .attr("id", "boards")
      .text("Loading Boards...")
      .appendTo("#output");

      Trello.get("/boards/YSP62hqc/lists", function(boards) {
          $boards.empty();
          $.each(boards, function(ix, board) {
            $("<h3>")
            .attr({href: board.url, target: "trello", value : board.id, name : board.id, id : board.id})
            .addClass("board")
            .text(board.name)
            .appendTo($boards);
            console.log("List Added");
            var resource = "/lists/" + board.id + "/cards";
            Trello.get(resource, function(cards) {
              $cards.empty();
              $.each(cards, function(ix, card) {
                console.log(card.labels[2]);
                $("<p>")
                .attr({target: "trello"})
                .addClass("card")
                .text(card.name)
                .appendTo($cards);
              });  
            });
            var $cards = $("<div>")
            .text("Loading Cards...")
            .appendTo($boards);
          });
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time when you call `$cards.empty();` and `appendTo($cards);`, `$cards` does not exist on the DOM, which is only declared and appended much later if I'm correct.

Try appending it to the DOM before trying to process it. ie.

```
var $boards = $("<div>")
   .attr("id", "boards")
   .text("Loading Boards...")
   .appendTo("#output");

 Trello.get("/boards/YSP62hqc/lists", function(boards) {
   $boards.empty();
   $.each(boards, function(id, board) {

     $("<h3>")
       .attr({ href: board.url, target: "trello", value: board.id, name: board.id, id: board.id })
       .addClass("board")
       .text(board.name)
       .appendTo($boards);

     var resource = "/lists/" + board.id + "/cards";

     var $cards = $("<div>")
       .text("Loading Cards...")
       .appendTo($boards);

     Trello.get(resource, function(cards) {
       $cards.empty();
       $.each(cards, function(ix, card) {
         $("<p>")
           .attr({ target: "trello" })
           .addClass("card")
           .text(card.name)
           .appendTo($cards);
       });
     });
   });
 });
```